# configure dnsmasq to give out addresses in different ranges

Tags: linux, dhcp, proxmox, dnsmasq

I'd like to give unknown clients an ip address in one range and known clients in another (that is a static one).

I tried quite a lot now and don't seem to get it working. All I get is an "no address available" error.

My network is 10.1.0.0/22 (<-!!!)
Guests should be assigned an address in the range 10.1.3.1-10.1.3.254
Static addresses are in range 10.1.2.1-10.1.2.254

so this is my config:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.0.2/22
    gateway 10.1.0.1

eth0@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.1.0.2/22 brd 10.1.3.255 scope global eth0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and

```
dhcp-range=tag:guests,10.1.3.1,10.1.3.254,255.255.252.0,12h
dhcp-range=tag:known,10.1.2.0,static,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,10.1.0.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,10.1.0.3
dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,10.1.0.1

dhcp-host=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,10.1.2.1
dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,10.1.3.2
```

Known hosts are given their addresses (regardless if its a .2. or .3. address) but unknown dont get anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problematic part was: tag:known. For some reason dnsmasq doesn't show something different in startup log messages when I remove it but now seems to work. (I cant tell if it works with /22 because I stoped using it.)

Answer (score 1):

To use a tag, it needs to be *set* somewhere. I do this for requests relayed from another subnet:

```
dhcp-range=set:wifi,192.168.4.0,static,255.255.255.0,24h
dhcp-option=tag:wifi,option:router,192.168.4.1
```

In the OP's case the dhcp-host entry would be the place to set the `known` tag, like this:

```
dhcp-host=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,10.1.2.1,set:known
```

However (from the dnsmasq manpage): **When a host matches any --dhcp-host directive (or one implied by /etc/ethers) then the special tag "known" is set.**

So that `set:known` is implicit. Using **!** to negate that tag, we can apply a different range to 'unknown' hosts:

```
dhcp-range=tag:!known,10.1.3.1,10.1.3.254,255.255.252.0,12h
dhcp-range=tag:known,10.1.2.0,static,255.255.252.0,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,10.1.0.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,10.1.0.3
dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,10.1.0.1

dhcp-host=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,10.1.2.1
dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,10.1.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving a netmask for the `tag:known` range, so dnsmasq will assume it's the entire /22, completely covering the `tag:guests` range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I do that? All my tries like: ```dhcp-range=tag:known,10.1.2.0,255.255.255.0,static,24h``` or ```dhcp-range=tag:known,10.1.2.1,10.1.2.254,255.255.255.0,static,24h``` result in dnsmasq not even starting. (bad dhcp-range at line 2 of /etc/dnsmasq.d/dhcp)

Comment: try `dhcp-range=tag:known,10.1.2.1,static,255.255.255.0,24h` (this is just a hunch, unfortunately I'm not able to test it right now ;-))

Comment: that does start but result (even in different 252/255 combinations) all in no address available :(